# The "export" keyword in the definition of Angular component class

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm not expert about Angular so probably I'll ask something very trivial.

Useful info about my system (obtain by the command `ng --version`)  are reported below:

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.0
Node: 16.13.2
Package Manager: npm 8.6.0
OS: linux x64
```

My question is about the code which defines a component. I suppose that the name of my component is `events`, so I execute the following command in a terminal:

```
ng generate component events
```

Previous command generates 4 files and in particular it creates the file `events.component.ts`.
Inside the file there is the declaration of the following class:

```
export class EventsComponent {
  ...
}
```

Why do I have to use the `export` keyword before the `class` keyword?
What is it for?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Angular, but to Typescript. If you want to use code (e.g. a class) in another `.ts` file, you have to first export it from your source file.

If you don't need to import it like `import {EventsComponent} from '.events.component'` somewhere in your project, you also don't need to export it before. Nevertheless this is not the case for angular components, since they should be used anywhere else (e.g. in a module).

Comment: Thank you Fabian, in fact in my module `app.module.ts` is present the instruction `import { EventsComponent } from './components/events/events.component'`.

Comment: In Java there are 2 keywords: `private` and `public`. If a method is defined `public` then is visible, else, if is defined `private`, it is not possible to call it outside the class where it is defined. If I have understood, `export` is as the Java keyword `public`, and by default, without `export`, a `TypeScript` class is not available for import in an other module.